# Conda environment: Print licenses of installed packages

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda, licensing

is there an easy way to print the license of each package in a conda environment?

`conda list` nicely lists all packages, however there is no option to get information about the license. On [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyzmq) the license is shown.

I tried to find the licenses in each package folder, but was not lucky. Is the only option to look at each package individually on `Anaconda.org`?

Conda version 4.6.14

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can find it in the JSON files under the `conda-meta` folder in each env.  The key `license` is in the main object, if you're looking to parse the JSON.  Otherwise, you can get a quick look with:

```
grep '"license":' conda-meta/*.json
```

which outputs the following (abridged) for me:

```
conda-meta/aioeasywebdav-2.4.0-py37_1000.json:  "license": "ISC",
conda-meta/aiohttp-3.5.4-py37h1de35cc_0.json:  "license": "Apache 2.0",
conda-meta/appdirs-1.4.3-py37h28b3542_0.json:  "license": "MIT",
conda-meta/appnope-0.1.0-py37_0.json:  "license": "BSD 2-Clause",
conda-meta/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py37_0.json:  "license": "MIT",
...
conda-meta/xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_4.json:  "license": "LGPL-2.1 and GPL-2.0",
conda-meta/yaml-0.1.7-hc338f04_2.json:  "license": "MIT",
conda-meta/yarl-1.3.0-py37h1de35cc_0.json:  "license": "Apache 2.0",
conda-meta/zeromq-4.2.5-h0a44026_1.json:  "license": "LGPL 3",
conda-meta/zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_3.json:  "license": "zlib",
```

Comment: Does this command list licenses of the packages installed with pip to the conda env?

Comment: @srctaha no it won't.

Comment: @srctaha For pip packages we can use [pip-licenses](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/).

Answer (score 0):

I found `pip-licenses` not to work in my `conda` env. Instead, you can get all `conda`-installed and `pip`-installed packages and their license info like so:

`conda list | awk '{if(NR>3) printf("%s=%s\n", $1, $2)}' | xargs conda info | grep 'name\|version\|license'`

which outputs

```
file name   : argon2-cffi-21.3.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0.conda
name        : argon2-cffi
version     : 21.3.0
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
file name   : argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0-py310h1a28f6b_0.conda
name        : argon2-cffi-bindings
version     : 21.2.0
license     : MIT
license_family: MIT
...
file name   : xz-5.2.5-h1a28f6b_1.conda
name        : xz
version     : 5.2.5
license     : LGPL-2.1-or-later and GPL-2.0-or-later
license_family: GPL2
file name   : zlib-1.2.12-h5a0b063_2.conda
name        : zlib
version     : 1.2.12
license     : Zlib
license_family: Other
file name   : zlib-1.2.12-h5a0b063_3.conda
name        : zlib
version     : 1.2.12
license     : Zlib
license_family: Other
```